# how to convert a listbox1.items to a bytearrayfile or byte in C#

Tags: c#, sql

i have tried this

```
byte[] byteArrayFile = File.ReadAllBytes(@""+listBox1.SelectedItem);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblVoice(flbVoice) VALUE (byteArrayFile");
```

i also want to put it on a sever
and this

```
byte[] byteArrayFile = File.ReadAllBytes(listBox1.SelectedItem);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblVoice(flbVoice) VALUE (byteArrayFile");
```

but Failed Please Help Thank You

Comment: You are missing a 'T' in 'INSERT'.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could be wrong with your existing code.

**Using `File.ReadAllBytes()`**

You are using the [`File.ReadAllBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) method which actually expects a file path. If your actual ListBox consists of file paths, then this may work just fine, but if it consists of other types of values it may fail. So just **make sure that you are actually using a file path here** :

```
// If your selection is a file path, then this should work
byte[] byteArrayFile = File.ReadAllBytes(Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem));
```

If you aren't using a file path, you may need to elaborate on what your actual ListBox contents looks like to determine the best way to convert it to a `byte[]`.

**Performing a Database Query (And Check Your Syntax)**

The command that you supplied on its own will not execute a database query. Database calls generally require a connection, which you will need to create that points to your target location :

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
{
      var query = "INSERT INTO tblVoice(flbVoice) VALUE (@file)";
      using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
      {
           connection.Open();
           // Pass your byte data as a parameter
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file",byteArrayFile);
           // Execute your parameter
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
}
```

Additionally, you were missing a 'T' in your INSERT statement, which has been corrected in the example above.